# Select text after two equal strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to make from a text file like this

```
CPRISM_{2}  

CPRISM_{2} top_material, bottom_material, side_material,  
n, h,  
x1, y1. alpha1, s1, mat1, 
... 
xn, yn, alphan, sn, matn 

junk junk junkkkkk
dawda
...

BPRISM_ 

BPRISM_ top_material, bottom_material, side_material,
n, h, radius, x1, y1, s1, ... xn, yn, sn
```

this

```
CPRISM_{2} top_material, bottom_material, side_material, n, h, x1, y1. alpha1, s1, mat1, ... xn, yn, alphan, sn, matn 

BPRISM_ top_material, bottom_material, side_material, n, h, radius, x1, y1, s1, ... xn, yn, sn
```

I know there is always some string, newline, the equal string and something i want to store, newline...

I tried some label tricks with sed, but I think that awk should be better for this.

```
awk '{cmd=$1;getline;if($0=""){getline;if(cmd==$1){print $0}}}' rg.txt
```

Does not output anything.

Comment: How do you know what is the first word of the line? Why is it `BPRISM` and not `dawda`?

Comment: That is it. Its SOMETHING, newline, SOMETHING, something important and newline again. To match what I want, there must be TWO EQUAL strings separated by newline. That is why dawda is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{cmd="";RS=""; ORS="\n"} $1==cmd{gsub(/\n/," "); print $0}; {cmd=$1}' test.txt
CPRISM_{2} top_material, bottom_material, side_material,   n, h,   x1, y1. alpha1, s1, mat1,  ...  xn, yn, alphan, sn, matn 
BPRISM_ top_material, bottom_material, side_material, n, h, radius, x1, y1, s1, ... xn, yn, sn
```

Looking at your `awk` scripting level, I guess, it is self explanatory script for you :).

**EDIT** for large record size:
Try this:

```
awk 'NF==1{cmd=$1;next} NF==0{next} $1==cmd{printf "%s", $0; while (1) { if (! getline tmp) break; if(length(tmp)) printf " %s", tmp; else break;};print ""}' test.txt
```

Hopefully, this will work for the large input file size.

Comment: Haha, awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
        FILENAME="rg.txt" FNR=1 NR=1

Comment: OK, this one liner script works for the input you mentioned in the question :-)
Trying to check if I can emulate `RS=""` programmatically.

Comment: @bartimar You did not mention file size..  Some golfing: `awk '$1==f{gsub(/\n/,FS);print $0} {f=$1}' RS= ORS="\n" file`

Comment: if you are golfing remove `$0` :)

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: After truncating the file to 5k lines, it prints nothing. Empty file. So it does not work...

Comment: Try the edit. Note: the edited code is only partially tested.

Comment: It works (partially)! Thanks! Problem was somewhere else. My debian seems to have vacations, he refuse to do any scripting. Tried it on cygwin and i works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^\s*\S+\s*$/{$!N;$!N;/^\s*(\S+)\s*\n\s*\n\s*\1\s*/!b;:a;$bb;N;/\n\s*$/!ba;:b;s/.*\n\s*\n//;s/\s*\n\s*/ /gp}' file
```

This matches the first three lines of the pattern and then removes the first two and appends subsequent lines until the end-of-file or a empty line and prints out the result.